# VBA: filter pivot table according to cell value

Tags: vba, excel, pivot

I have a pivot table which I want to dynamically filter based on the last two days (so for 4th of Jan it'd be 2nd and 3rd of Jan.). I already have the VBA code down to insert the newest pivot data (into the HISTORICALS sheet). Then, I retrieve the last two days (variables defined as Highest_Max & Second_Highest_Max).

My idea was then to paste the two newest dates into cells in the PIVOT sheet (where the pivot is located) and filter the pivot based on the value in these cells (B34 & B35). Unfortunately, the filtering option is where my code is stuck:

```
Sub Select_Last_Two_Days()


    With Worksheets("HISTORICALS")

' select the two newest dates

    Highest_Max = Format(WorksheetFunction.Max(.Range("A:A")), "Short Date")
    Second_Highest_Max = Format(WorksheetFunction.Large(.Range("A:A"), WorksheetFunction.CountIf(.Range("A:A"), WorksheetFunction.Max(.Range("A:A"))) + 1), "Short Date")
    Debug.Print Highest_Max, Second_Highest_Max

' paste results into cells in PIVOT sheet
    Worksheets("PIVOT").Range("B34").Value = Highest_Max
    Worksheets("PIVOT").Range("B35").Value = Second_Highest_Max
End With

' update pivot according to cell values (B34/B35)

With Worksheets("PIVOT").PivotTables(PivotTable1)
    .PivotFields("ipg:date").ClearAllFilters
    .PivotFields("ipg:date").PivotFilters.Add Type:=xlCaptionEquals, Value1:=[B34].Value, Value2:=[B35].Value
End With

End Sub
```

I receive the following error: "Unable to get the PivotTables property of the Worksheet class."

When I click debug, the following line is shown to be wrong:

```
With Worksheets("PIVOT").PivotTables(PivotTable1)
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? Been researching for the last couple of hours, but can't manage to find a fix. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Should PivotTable1 have quotes around it? 

With Worksheets("PIVOT").PivotTables("PivotTable1")

Comment: Thanks, now the following line is wrong though: .PivotFields("ipg:date").PivotFilters.Add Type:=xlCaptionEquals, Value1:=[B34].Value, Value2:=[B35].Value

Comment: "Application defined or object defined error" is what I get as the error message then.

Comment: Try 

Worksheets("PIVOT").range("B34") etc

instead of [B34].Value

Comment: .PivotFields("ipg:date").PivotFilters.Add Type:=xlCaptionEquals, Value1:=Worksheets("PIVOT").Range("B34").Value, Value2:=Worksheets("PIVOT").Range("B35").Value gives me the same application/object defined error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want something more like this:

```
    Dim pvItem As PivotItem

        'make all values in the filter true to start with
        With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable4").PivotFields("Date")

            For Each pvItem In .PivotItems
                 pvItem.Visible = True
            Next pvItem

        End With

        With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable4").PivotFields("Date")
            For Each pvItem In .PivotItems

                If Format(pvItem.Name, "dd/mm/yyyy") <> Sheets("PIVOT").Range("B34") And Format(pvItem.Name, "dd/mm/yyyy") <> Sheets("PIVOT").Range("B35") Then
                    pvItem.Visible = False
                End If

            Next pvItem

        End With
```

The date format will need changing to suit your needs - but in essence, you need to make all items ticked in the filter, before you can start. Then untick all apart from the 2 you want

THIS CODE WORKS ON YOUR FILE - ONCE YOU RECREATE THE PIVOT TABLE (changing the sheet name, and the pivot table name...)

```
        Sub Pivot_Test()

        Dim pvItem As PivotItem

                'make all values in the filter true to start with

                    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").RefreshTable

            With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("ipg:date")

                For Each pvItem In .PivotItems

                            pvItem.Visible = True

                    Next pvItem

            End With

            Dim dte1 As Date
            Dim dte2 As Date

            dte1 = CDate(Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B34"))
            dte2 = CDate(Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B35"))

                With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("ipg:date")
                    For Each pvItem In .PivotItems

                        If Format(pvItem.Name, "mm/dd/yyyy") <> dte1 And Format(pvItem.Name, "mm/dd/yyyy") <> dte2 Then
                            pvItem.Visible = False
                        End If

                    Next pvItem

                End With

        End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort, but I'll get stuck at the following line: pvItem.Visible = True

Comment: The error message is "Unable to set the Visible property of the PivotItem class"

Comment: In the date filter have you ticked the "Allow multiple items" box?

Comment: Can you show an example of what this pivot table looks like?

Comment: here is a link to the file (the table is a little too big to be displayed in a picture): https://www.file-upload.net/download-12903481/CPSDashboardII.xlsm.html  // my code is located under Module 4, yours under Module 5.

Comment: Really appreciate you taking the time!

Comment: I think your pivot table has become messed up with the code you have been running.

So... I recreated it (you know when it's right because the only options in the date filter should be the 4 dates in the HISTORICAL sheet). 

Then the code works (albeit with some messing about with dates but due to UK/US format). Code added above that just worked

Comment: THANKS A LOT! Can you send me the file you worked on? Because I still get an error message even though I created a new pivot and changed the names in the formula accordingly..

Comment: can you send me a link to the new file

Comment: Hey, I just made it work, I had some issues with the pivot syntax. THANK YOU VERY MUCH! :-)

Comment: I used your loop and it works but it takes forever to run the code when the filter countains a lot of values...